# Importing reference tables to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I need to narrow down what google analytics down by modules that arent collected by google analytics. Is there a way to upload a table that analytics will essentially reference and vlookup off of?

IE analytics tracks Page Name and Page Address, but I want to be able to track Page Names and Page Addresses by modules I define.

IE
Page Name: Landing Page
Page Address: LandingPage/Index
Module: Setup

I want the reports to show an additional column called "Modules" and it will have every Page Name and Page Address I have tagged with the module "setup" (essentially a vlookup). So I can basically see site use by Module (categories I define)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the information you need as custom dimension at the hit-level, so in the landing page report (or page report) in Google Analytics, add this dimension as a secondary dimension and you'll get the second column with the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly this seems to be what [content groups](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en) in Google Analytics are for.

Custom Dimensions, as answered by Michele, is also a possibility. You can upload custom dimension via the [Data Import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191589?hl=en) feature in Google Analytics. The caveat is that, unless you have a GA360 account, uploads are not applied to historical data - you load your lookup table up to GA, it takes up to 48 hours until it's processed, and starting from then the lookup data will be applied to the incoming hits (GA360 has "query time" imports that allow to apply data to existing data). So there is no big advantage over sending data at collection time for this specific use case.

So, if you want to group by module I would suggest you create a content group (either via the tracking code or by extracting info from the page path or page title) that you can then use as secondary dimension or in custom reports, filters and segments.